Evaluate $\int {\frac{\sin {8x}}{\sin^4{x}+\cos^4{x}}}dx$
I have solved 3 similar questions before where instead of $\sin{8x}$ there were $1$, $\sin{x}$, $\sin{2x}$ and they were pretty easy but using double angle formula in this one gave me a numerator of
$$\frac{\sin {x} \cos {x} \cos {2x} \cos4x}{\sin^4{x}+\cos^4{x}}$$ and doing the double formulas on cos terms seems like a mammoth task is there any approach that I could try Or is the long way the right way?

Remark - a backslash makes common functions look nicer. Compare \sin x which renders $\sin x$ with sin x which gives $sin x$.

I would start with $\cos^4 x + \sin^4 x = \frac 14 \cos 4x + \frac 34.$

Using Double-Angle Formulas: $\begin{align}
\int_{} \frac{\sin (8x)}{\sin ^4(x)+\cos^{\ 4}(x)}dx&=\int_{}\frac{\sin (8x)}{(\frac{1-\cos (2x)}{2}\ )^2+ (\frac{\cos (2x)+1}{2})\ ^2}dx \\&= \int_{} \frac{4\sin (4x) \cos (4x)}{1+\cos ^{\ 2}(2x)}\ dx \\
 &=\int_{} \frac{8\sin(2x)\cos(2x)}{2- \sin^{\ 2}(2x)}\ dx- \int_{} \frac{16\sin ^{\ 3}(2x)\cos (2x)}{2-\sin^{\ 2}(2x)}\ dx \end{align}$
Then use $\cos(2x)dx=\frac{1}{2}d \sin (2x).$

\begin{align}
&\int_{} \frac{\sin 8x}{\sin ^4x+\cos^{\ 4}x}dx
\\
&=\int_{}\frac{\sin 8x}{1-\frac12 \sin^2 2x}dx 
= \int_{} \frac{8\sin 4x \cos 4x}{3+\cos 4x}\ dx \\
 &= -\int_{} \frac{2\cos 4x}{3+\cos 4x}\ d(\cos 4x) \\
 &=-2\cos 4x + 6\ln(3+\cos4x)+C \end{align}

We use the following trigonometric identities: $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1;\ \sin2\theta=2\sin\theta\cos\theta;\ \cos2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$.
We simplify the denominator of the integrand as follows: $$\begin{aligned}\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x)^2+(\cos^2x)^2&=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\cdot\sin^2x\cdot\cos^2x\\&=1-\frac24\left(2\sin x\cdot\cos x\right)^2\\&=\frac12\left(2-\sin^2(2x)\right)\\&=\frac12\left(2-\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{2}\right)\\&=\frac{\cos(4x)+3}4\end{aligned}$$
We can evaluate the given antiderivative by substitution $u=\cos(4x)+3$, i.e., $\cos(4x)=u-3$ so that $\mathrm du=-4\sin(4x)\ \mathrm dx$.
Now,
$$\begin{aligned}\int\dfrac{\sin(8x)}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}\ \mathrm dx&=\int\dfrac{4\cdot2\sin(4x)\cos(4x)}{\cos(4x)+3}\ \mathrm dx\\&=\int\dfrac{2(3-u)}{u}\ \mathrm du\\&=6\int\dfrac{\mathrm du}{u}-2\int\mathrm du\\&=6\ln u-2u+C_1\end{aligned}$$$$\color{blue}{\boxed{\int\dfrac{\sin(8x)}{\sin^4x+\cos^4x}\ \mathrm dx=6\ln\left(\cos(4x)+3\right)-2\cos(4x)+C}}$$
where $C$ is the constant of integration.
Also, see what WolframAlpha says about this.
Hope this helps!

$$\text{Consider } \sin^4x+\cos^4x, \text{ recalling the trig identity } \sin^2\kappa = \frac1 2(1-\cos(2\kappa))$$
$$(\sin^2x)^2 + (1-\sin^2x)^2 = 2(\sin^2x)^2-2\sin^2x+1 $$
$$= 2(\frac1 2(1-\cos(2x)))^2 - 2(\frac1 2(1-\cos(2x)))+1$$
$$=\frac 1 2 (\cos^2(2x)+1)$$
And now again using $\sin^2 \kappa + \cos^2 \kappa = 1$,
$$=\frac1 2 ((1-\sin^2(2x))+1) = \frac1 2 ((1-(\frac1 2(1-\cos(4x))))+1)$$
$$= \frac{1 }4\cos(4x)+\frac3 4$$
You may now proceed by substitution! Done.

Then you have sin/cos which is similar to u/du, so you may find d/dx log(cos) or log(sin) to help you find the answer. Good Luck.
